# Can't hide fields using jquery on radio change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning javascript script and trying to hide some fields on radio change. It doesn't work, but I can't see why and there are no console errors. This is what I am trying:

HTML

```
    <form>
  <input type="text" name="field_0" id="field_0" value=" " class='text_box'>
  <input type="text" name="field_1" id="field_1" value=" " class='text_box'>
  <input type='radio' name='field_2' id='field_2_0' value="I can come" class='form_radio'>
  <input type='radio' name='field_2' id='field_2_1' value="I can't come" class='form_radio'>
  <input type='hidden' name='field_2_length' value='2'>
  <input class="extra" type="text" name="field_3" id="field_3" value=" " class='text_box'>
  <input class="extra" type="text" name="field_4" id="field_4" value=" " class='text_box'>
  <input type='submit' value='Send' class='form_button'>
</form>
```

JS

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('input:radio[name=field_2]').change(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 'hide') {
       $('.extra').hide();
     } else {
       $('.extra').show();
     }
   });

 });
```

This is the code (not) running
https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/s25stbde/2/

Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Neither radio has `value='hide'`. Not clear why that would be expected value in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for testing the value of `$('input:radio[name=field_2]')` is looking for a value of 'hide' when it should be looking for a value of "I can't come".  Change your javascript code to

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('input:radio[name=field_2]').change(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == "I can't come") {
       $('.extra').hide();
     } else {
       $('.extra').show();
     }
   });

 });
```

See working fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/mcebb8py/1/

Answer (score 1):

In your version the 2 radio values are "I can come" and "I can't come",

So the case you're checking in your change handler, `$(this).val() == 'hide'` never happens.

Here's an example changing one of the values of radio inputs to "hide":

```js
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('input:radio[name=field_2]').change(function() {
         console.log('this ', $(this).val())
         if ($(this).val() == 'hide') {
           $('.extra').hide();
         } else {
           $('.extra').show();
         }
       });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="field_0" id="field_0" value=" " class='text_box'>
  <input type="text" name="field_1" id="field_1" value=" " class='text_box'>
  <input type='radio' name='field_2' id='field_2_0' value="hide" class='form_radio'>
  <!-- changed value to hide -->
  <input type='radio' name='field_2' id='field_2_1' value="I can't come" class='form_radio'>
  <input type='hidden' name='field_2_length' value='2'>
  <input class="extra" type="text" name="field_3" id="field_3" value=" " class='text_box'>
  <input class="extra" type="text" name="field_4" id="field_4" value=" " class='text_box'>
  <input type='submit' value='Send' class='form_button'>
</form>
```